# what is the difference between ol.Map and ol.PluggableMap in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I can see 2 kinds of map in openlayers , default map class and ol.PluggableMap .

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'm_gmap_1',
    controls: []})

and pluggableMap = new ol.PluggableMap({
 target: 'm_gmap_1',
        controls: []})
}),
```

could anyone please tell me difference

Answer (score 3):

For an answer, you have to take a look at [the PR (Pull Request) "Pluggable renderers"](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/6855) on OpenLayers repository.

You will see that it's to remove some dependencies in particular when you just want to use only one renderer (smaller build)

Comment: thanks , the reason why i have asked this question is , when i extent ol.control.control in my own class and tried to add custom controls , the setMap function is removing my control , and setMap function is accepting pluggable map , could you please take a look at this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285379